# I am using google directions api to draw a route on map, it is working fine in chrome but taking very long time to response in android app

Tags: android, google-directions-api

I am using google directions api to draw a route on map, it is working fine in chrome but taking very long time to response in android app

i am using directions api url to get response, it was working fine when i have integrated it 2 days before when i tried it today it is taking very long time like 2,3 minutes to response

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue so that the community could help you better.